# chrome extension OnMessage

Tags: google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie at Chrome extensions, and of course I stuck on every step, but this is specially hard. Maybe it is a silly mistake, but here is what I am trying to do:

Send a simple message from the content script to the background page and handle it as a variable. So I have this in my content script:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var d = document.domain;    
       chrome.extension.sendMessage({dom: d});  

 });
```

And in my background script this:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    alert(request.dom);
});
```

So, the alert works fine. But it "goes" to the page I am browing and not the HTML extension, this means, instead of poping up when clicking on my extension button, it will appear as it was coded into the content script when the page loads.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ain't sure what you are expecting, but based on `But it "goes" to the page I am browing and not the HTML extension, this means, instead of poping up when clicking on my extension button, it will appear as it was coded into the content script when the page loads.` i assume you are expecting alert() only after you click on extension button ? If it is true, then you are going wrong, because you have added listener on background script not in browser action and this is expected behavior, it would be great if you can post all your related code and expectations clearly, so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Basically what I am trying to do is simply pass a value from the content script to the background script. Then assign it to a variable and handle it (in the background script), then show that value in the popup when clicking on my extension icon. 

The code I have posted before is basically all what I did so far. 

How can I add it to the browser action? Simply: How would you do what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My Demo extension is as follows

**Files & Roles**

a) *manifest.json* [(Documentation)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

b) *myscript.js* (Content Script See [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html))

c) *background.js* (Background HTML File See [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html))

d) *popup.html* (Browser Action Popup See [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups))

e) *popup.js* (Receptor of Modified value from Background Page)

***manifest.json***

Registered all files to manifest(Viz background,popup,content scripts) with permissions

```
{
"name":"Communication Demo",
"description":"This demonstrates modes of communication",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1",
"permissions":["<all_urls>"],
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
}  
}
```

***myscript.js***

Used [sendMessage() API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) for communicating with background page

```
var d = document.domain;
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    dom: d
});
```

***background.js***

Added Event Listeners for Content and popup.js using [onMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#type-Port) and [onConnect()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#type-Port) Listeners

```
var modifiedDom;
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    modifiedDom = request.dom + "Trivial Info Appending";
});
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        if (message == "Request Modified Value") {
            port.postMessage(modifiedDom);
        }
    });
});
```

***popup.html***

Sample browser action HTML Page registering popup.js to avoid [Inline Scripting](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

***popup.js***

Used [Port\Long Lived Connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#type-Port) for communicating with background page for fetching results

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({
    name: "Sample Communication"
});
port.postMessage("Request Modified Value");
port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    console.log("Modified Value recieved is  " + msg);
});
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more information

Comment: **Important note**, messaging functions from `chrome.extension` have been since deprecated. Use `chrome.runtime` equivalents.